# Математические формулы в Borland C++ 5.02

Tags: c++

Хотелось бы получить поддержку, вот условие. Дано действительные числа y, z, натуральное число n и генерируемого случайное натуральное число x (x = 0 ... n). Вычислить формулу. Вывести целую часть результата.Помогите разобраться в ошибках,что не так?Запрашивает то что где-то не там скобка,и матюкается на random(x).
Вот мое решение задачи такого типа:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
main()
{
    float y, z, a;
    unsigned int n;
    random(x);
    printf("y=");
    scanf("%f", &y);
    printf("z=");
    scanf("%f", &z);
    printf("a=");
    scanf("%f", &a);
    printf("n=");
    scanf("%f", &n);
    randomize();
    a = (5(pow(x, 5)) * log 10(y) + 5) / (4 pow(y, 2) * e(sinz) - x / y + 1);
    printf("Result=%8.5f", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переменная x не объявлена. Нет стандартной функции random(.) и randomize(). Есть rand() и srand(int). Там где формула вычисляется - вообще хаос какой-то. 
Хочется уточнить, пытался ли автор вопроса посмотреть хоть какой-нибудь справочник по языку Си, прежде чем писать сюда? Рекомендую начать с Кернигана и Ритчи "Язык программирования Си". Все-таки портал, как мне кажется, не для изучения основ синтаксиса предназначен. Написать работающий код не проблема - но хочется, чтобы портал помогал самостоятельной работе, а не заменял её.